# Please help understanding how the 'return' statement is used in this example

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently learning python using Learn Python the Hard Way and really enjoying it. In one of the lesson examples, there is a use of 'return' that I fail to grasp.

The lesson I'm stuck on is [Exercise 43: Gothons From Planet Percal #25](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html). I understand that when the game is first run `next_room_name` is set to `central_corridor` and so `central_corridor()` is called during the first loop under `play()`.
What I don't understand is how `self.start` get's re-assigned.

For example, in the instance of `death` being returned under `central_corridor()`. After the return on line 49, we're back in the `play(self): while True` loop. The first line is `next_room_name = self.start` As far as I know, `self.start` still equals `central_corridor`, but it apparently is now equalling `death`.

Does this mean that after `death` is returned, and still in the `while` loop under `play()`, the object `Game()` has been reinitialized, the `__init__` being fed the results of the return? I'm confused how the `next_room_name = self.start` under `__init__` is being reassigned to `death` when we're technically still in the `play(self): while True` loop and haven't exited it. I guess I'm confused as to where `death` is being returned to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's walk through a few steps of it up until the `while` loop:

```
a_game = Game("central_corridor")
a_game.play()
```

Here we instantiate `a_game`, with the `start_value` = `central_corridor`. So far, so good :) Now we run `a_game.play()`:

```
def play(self):
    next_room_name = self.start

    while True:
        print "\n--------"
        room = getattr(self, next_room_name)
        next_room_name = room()
```

As you correctely stated, `next_room_name` gets assigned the value `central_corridor`, and then the `while` loop begins.

This may be the important part to get - the `while` loop only executes the `while` piece and everything indented undnerneath it - `next_room_name` is **not** reassigned to `self.start` each time. Instead, we define `room` as the attribute `next_room_name` (which is `central_corridor`), and then run the method of the same name. The return value of that method (let's say `death`) is then used in the next loop, meaning that `room = death`, `next_room_name=` the result of `death()`, which prints a random quip and then exits. If the name were another room, it would continue the loop.

Comment: Your description was key to my understanding. just as in `__init__(self, start)` where `start` is looking for a value to be passed in, `room = getattr(self, next_room_name)` is also looking for a value to be passed in. It isn't absolutely defined as `self.start`, it's only passed in this value on the first iteration of the loop. OK, I think I got it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @VinBreau You got it :) Happy it helped!

Answer (score 3):

`self.start` is never reassigned. The return on line 49 doesn't return to the start of the `play()` method, it returns to

```
next_room_name = room()
```

The line `next_room_name = self.start` is not in the `while` loop at all, so it never happens after the first time. `next_room_name` is just set to `death` because that's what the `central_corridor` method returned.

Comment: +1 - I was midway through typing mine when you answered and didn't have the heart to delete (although yours is clearer/more succinct :) ).

Comment: OK. So when `death` is returned in line 49, we go back to line 19, `room = getattr(self, next_room_name)` replaces `next_room_name` with whatever was returned? Is that correct? I think I get it.

Comment: @VinBreau: No: the line `next_room_name = room()` is the line that replaces `next_room_name` with whatever was returned.